# calculate returns for a financial time series with trading signals

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a financial time series **`data`** for which i want to calculate `Returns` , `Maximum Draw down` etc based on a **`signal`** series . My actual time series is a big one. I am giving here a toy example so that i can tell want i need. Here `1` is for `buy` signal and `-1` is for `sell` signal. I initiate and hold the trade position till the opposite signal is received and then reverse the position ans so on. `Returns` should be calculated for every data point so that an `Equity Curve` can be plotted.

```
data<- rnorm(20,100,3)
signal<- c( 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1)
```

For this purpose `Quantmod` and `PerformanceAnalytics` comes to my mind.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can transform your price time series 
(I assume it is `data` in your example: the values should probably be positive)
and your signal time series 
into time series with the values of each asset in your portfolio
(with cash, you have two assets);
the sum of those time series is the value of your portfolio,
from which you can compute the returns, VaR, etc. (`PerformanceAnalytics` will do that part for you).
You can do the transformation manually (easier) or with the `quantstrat` package (more generic and safer).

Comment: I have seen Matlab a lot in finance. Is also R used? That would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea of the R financial packages (I wish I knew). I am guessing that your main problem is to know when to trade and when not to trade, and, that after figuring out that, your problem is solved.

First you may try with a pure R solution. I am a fan of `Reduce` so you may try with this.

```
deltaTrade <- function(currentTrend,nextSignal) ifelse(lastOp != nextSignal,1,-1)
trade <- Reduce('deltaTrade',signal,init=signal[1],accumulate=TRUE)
tradePeriods = which(trade==1)
```

If it is too slow I have recently seen in other SO questions that switching to C++ for an efficient solution is a good way to tackle the problem. You can do that with the `cpp` package, which apparently has become a real hip.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("NumericVector selectTrades(NumericVector x, NumericVector out) {
  int n = x.length();
  int current = x[0];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (x[i] == current) {
      out[i] = 0; // hold position
    } else {
      current = x[i];
      out[i] = 1; // play position
    }
  }
  return out;
}")

trades = which(selectTrades(signal,out)==1)
```

Anyway, I hope that any of these helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But i have solved the problem with the help of a library called "PerformanceAnalytic" in R to some extent.